Baking animations with modifiers to export to unity
Description:
I made a track animation for my PS1-style tank. It uses a curve modifier so that the track links follow along a certain path, I followed this tutorial here. I want to export this model with that animation so I tried to bake the animation. However, the animation doesn't bake all of the movement of each individual track link but instead just the keyframe of it moving. (This movement is what makes the track links move along the curve). This means once I have baked the animation and I try to apply the modifier the animation breaks. The reason I want to export this model and its animation is to import it into my Unity project. I found someone who has achieved my desired effect here, however, he does really thoroughly explain how he did it and he isn't really responsive to questions. I'm wondering if I am just using the wrong bake settings or some other reason. I have tried exporting as an Alembic file type, however, Unity's support of this file type is not great plus it didn't really work when I tried it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Image:

Useful info:
Version: blender 3.4.1
Unity primarily uses: .fbx and .obj formats
Link to tutorial: here
Link to the desired result: here

Animation baking does not make sense in this context. The curve modifier output is a deformed geometry. The animation baking is when you apply all procedural transformation to rig bones. Each link would have to have its own bone. The thing is that it is the Armature Modifier that has its counterpart in Unity that allows for this.


It is kind of wasteful to have some many bones for track links. I believe game engines should have their own logic to move the links without skeletal animation, supported by physics system and procedural. Or come up with clever tricks like using a looped shape key that is only animated for a link length movement or animating the shader to make the links mesh appear moving.
